# Avoid need to refresh after submitting form in OOP PHP

Tags: php, forms, oop, submit

When i use a MVC framework in OOP PHP, and  i submit a form, i have to refresh the page to go on to the next "elseif".

Even though the function "$login->isConfigFileCreated()" now returns true (after the class constructer have been executed) it shows the same view as before, and requires a refresh to "move on".

I know for sure, that the problem isn't in the "createConfigFile() function". This is a common problem for me.

```
<?php

require_once("db.php");
require_once("classes/Login.php");

$login = new Login();

**if ($login->isConfigFileCreated() == false)
{
    include("views/config_file.php");
}
elseif ($login->isAdminCreated() == false)
{
    include("views/register.php");
}**
else
{
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

The config_file.php view file looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="create_config_file">
        <input type="text" name="input_db_host" required />
        <input type="text" name="input_db_name" required />
        <input type="text" name="input_db_user" required />
        <input type="text" name="input_db_pass" required />
        <input type="submit" name="create_config_file" value="Create" />
</form>
```

And the class, with the functions, looks like this for example:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["create_config_file"]))
        {
            $this->createConfigFile();
        }
        if (isset($_POST["register"]))
        {
            $this->register();
        }
    }
public function isAdminCreated()
    {
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno)
        {
            $checksetup = $this->db_connection->query("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_id = '1';");
            if ($checksetup->num_rows == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


public function isConfigFileCreated()
    {
        if(defined('DB_HOST') && defined('DB_NAME') && defined('DB_USER') && defined('DB_PASS'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function createConfigFile($action)
    {
        if ($action == "complete")
        {
            $file_content = file_get_contents("db.php");
            $file_content .= 'define("CONFIG_DONE", "true");';
            file_put_contents("db.php", $file_content);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db_connection = new mysqli($_POST['input_db_host'], $_POST['input_db_user'], $_POST['input_db_pass'], $_POST['input_db_name']);
            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno)
            {
                $file_content =    '<?php'."\n";
                $file_content .=   'define("DB_HOST", "'.$_POST['input_db_host'].'");'."\n";
                $file_content .=   'define("DB_NAME", "'.$_POST['input_db_name'].'");'."\n";
                $file_content .=   'define("DB_USER", "'.$_POST['input_db_user'].'");'."\n";
                $file_content .=   'define("DB_PASS", "'.$_POST['input_db_pass'].'");'."\n";

                file_put_contents("db.php", $file_content);
                fclose("db.php");
                $login->messages[] = "That's it! You're now ready to kick ass at some image management!";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errors[] = "Wrong database credentials!"; 
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you expand on your scenario and the question please. What do you mean by 'i have to refresh the page to go on to the next "elseif"' And what does the code have to do with it?

Comment: Yeah I am not exactly sure what your question is either

Comment: The code shows the config_file.php if the function isConfigFileCreated() returns false. Then i fill out the form, and press submit. The page reloads, the constructer runs, sees that i pressed submit, and creates the config file. All this happens in the line "$login = new Login();" since the constructer checks for $_POST.

But after all this, ir checks what to display, and displays config_file.php AGAIN. Even though the file has been created.

But when i refresh one time, it "moves on".

Comment: Can you post the code for `createConfigFile()` and `isConfigFileCreated()`?

Comment: But i'm sute the functions themselves, isn't the problem. It is something about the code "structure" and not the individual functions. All functions works properly, but the index.php where it's determined what view to show, has some kind of error, since it requires a refresh to "move on".

Comment: Thanks for posting that. It is an order problem with the require that you are doing. I've updated my answer below with more details. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db.php is included before before the `createConfigFiles` function executes.

You either need to define the variables in the `createConfigFiles` function, as well as creating the file:

```
public function createConfigFile($action)
{
    if ($action == "complete")
    {
        $file_content = file_get_contents("db.php");
        $file_content .= 'define("CONFIG_DONE", "true");';
        file_put_contents("db.php", $file_content);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli($_POST['input_db_host'], $_POST['input_db_user'], $_POST['input_db_pass'], $_POST['input_db_name']);
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno)
        {
            $file_content =    '<?php'."\n";
            $file_content .=   'define("DB_HOST", "'.$_POST['input_db_host'].'");'."\n";
            $file_content .=   'define("DB_NAME", "'.$_POST['input_db_name'].'");'."\n";
            $file_content .=   'define("DB_USER", "'.$_POST['input_db_user'].'");'."\n";
            $file_content .=   'define("DB_PASS", "'.$_POST['input_db_pass'].'");'."\n";

            file_put_contents("db.php", $file_content);
            fclose("db.php");
            define("DB_HOST", $_POST['input_db_host']);
            define("DB_NAME", $_POST['input_db_name']);
            define("DB_USER", $_POST['input_db_user']);
            define("DB_PASS", $_POST['input_db_pass']);;
            $login->messages[] = "That's it! You're now ready to kick ass at some image management!";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->errors[] = "Wrong database credentials!"; 
        }
    }

}
```

Or you could do this if Login will never use the database on __construct:

```
require_once("classes/Login.php");

$login = new Login();

require_once("db.php");
```

Doing both is unnecessary!

Answer (score 1):

The `elseif` will make all of the code related. If you don't want it to be related and want it to continue and check the next if statement, then just remove the else:

```
if ($login->isConfigFileCreated() == false)
{
    include("views/config_file.php");
}

if ($login->isAdminCreated() == false)
{
    include("views/register.php");
}

if( !$login->isConfigFileCreated() && $login->isAdminCreated())
{
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

This will include the config_file.php and then check to see if the admin was created

After your input here is an updated answer:

So the problem is that the file you are writing to is `db.php` which has already been included in the script.

So the flow is `require db.php` -> then write to that file. That means that the changes you wrote to this file will not be available since the script was already loaded.

The solution here would be to not use constant variables since they cannot be changed. If you use regular variables then you can just `include db.php` again to override the variables that were defined before.

The other option would be to have your create config files return the values that need to be defined so that you can override what was already included earlier.

Comment: When I do that, the functions fails, and nothing is displayed.